# Conditional validation using scenarios in yii2

Tags: forms, validation, yii2

I am trying to validate my form in edit scenario where if `CandidateResumeName` is not filled, I want to require this field. This is how I am trying, but it's not working.

```
[['CandidateResumeName'], 'required', 'when' => function($model) {                              
                if($model->HRMS_CandidateResumeName == "")
                    return true;
                },'on' => 'edit'],
```

Please help!

Comment: The required validator will already check for empty values.

Comment: I want to check in case $model->HRMS_CandidateResumeName is null

Comment: Have you SET the `edit` scenario ?

Comment: Yes I have set it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the inner array

```
 ['CandidateResumeName', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {                              
            if($model->HRMS_CandidateResumeName == "")
                return true;
            },'on' => 'edit'],
```

Remember to define and set the `edit`  scenario properly

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should look like this

```
['CandidateResumeName', 'required', 'on' => 'edit'],
```

Custom Scenario:

In your model

```
public function scenarios(){
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['edit'] = ['CandidateResumeName'];
        return $scenarios;
    }
```

Controller

```
public function  actionCreate(){
  ---     
 $model->scenario = 'edit';
  ---
}
```